# Unix Shell for loop based on an argument

Tags: shell, unix, iterator

- OS = Ubuntu
- Filename = generate_zips.sh

I'm trying to create a bunch of files (number based on an arugment). However It is not working.

```
#!/bin/sh
LIMIT=$1
for ((a=1; a <= LIMIT; a++)) 
do
    mkdir zips
    cd zips
    touch $a
done
```

but its returning this

```
esauer@ubuntu:~/repo/filecheck/src/plugins/archive$ ./generate_zips.sh 10
./generate_zips.sh: 4: ./generate_zips.sh: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable
```

I cant figure out whats wrong...

Comment: (i) That's bash syntax, not sh, so you should start off with `#! /bin/bash` -- it's possible your `/bin/sh` isn't bash or isn't acting like it.  (ii) Try `touch "$a"` to force $a to be a string. (iii) you probably want to put the `mkdir zips; cd zips` outside the loop, to avoid creating a deep tree of directories.  But apart from that... dunno.

Comment: `/bin/sh` is a POSIX-conforming shell.  Either change to POSIX code, or use `/bin/bash` to use so-called "bashisms".

Comment: BTW, inside the loop, use: `mkdir zips && cd zips && touch $a`, so the  loop will fail correctly.

Comment: Yeah I realized that when it worked. Thanks tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shebang is wrong - you're using a `bash` feature (the "C-style" for-loop in double parens) but you specified `/bin/sh`. Change that to `/bin/bash`.

You can also change your for-loop so that it doesn't use `bash`'s special features, of course (see the other answers). This is somewhat more portable, as not all Unix-like systems have `/bin/bash` (but pretty much all of them have `/bin/sh`). However, `bash` is pretty wide-spread, too (it's the standard shell in most Linux distributions, for example).

Comment: /bin/sh is a just different shell - in practice, on ubuntu and debian it's a shell called `dash` - but historically, it's the `bourne shell`. The style of the for-loop you used is not supported in those shells.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
LIMIT=$1

for a in $(seq 1 $LIMIT)
do
  mkdir -p zips
  touch zips/$a
done
```

Comment: And yeah, see what @rwos said :)

Comment: I'm running its like ./generate_zips.sh 10

Comment: `$( ... )` is another modern extension.  It is POSIX, but not Bourne compatible.  A few systems use a shell with a small footprint as /bin/sh.

Answer (score 0):

I might do it something like this...

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir zips
cd zips
a=1; while [ $a -le $1 ]; do
  touch $a
  a=$(($a + 1))
done
```

There are bash-specific ways that are a bit shorter but this will work on any Posix shell.